# facebook post link type get larger image with spring facebook api

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social

I'm trying to receive a larger image out of a facebook post link but I only receive a 130x130 sized image

Using springs facebook api (v1.0.3) gives me the option to use a `LinkPost` object and call `linkPost.getPicture()` on it. The result here is the following.

> https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBWk3G0lcbf1KI2&w=130&h=130&url=fbstaging%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Fstaging_resources%2FMDExNDIwODQ3NzY0NjEyNTI5OjE0MDg4OTQ0ODY%3D&cfs=1&sx=210&sy=0&sw=1200&sh=1200&_nc_hash=AQCTiB_3PRlY3Uee

[image: The 130x130 image]

Having a `PhotoPost` object I'm receiving a list of images when using MediaOperations Class.

Can anybody tell me if it's even possible to get larger pictures out of a *Link* Post?

Comment: Did you try full_picture? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679599/php-facebook-graph-api-and-full-or-larger-size-post-images

Comment: I'm using the Spring API for it - so adding a Request Param would be an ugly workaround